# In springBoot JPA findById() taking only id of integer type. I want to find it by emailID. Is there any method like findByEmailId?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I am using SpringBootApplication with JPA to define Controller mappings and to perform CRUD operations.
I want to fetch student details from database by emailId
I have written SQL query in DAO but it returning sql row in String format
How can I map to the StudentDetail object?
findById taking only id of integer type. I want to find it by emailID. Is there any method like findByEmailId?

StudentDetail.java

```
@Table(name="studentpersonaldetails")
@Entity
public class StudentDetail {

    @Id
    @Column(name="emailid")
    String emailId;
    @Column(name="firstname")
    String firstName;
    @Column(name="lastname")
    String lastName;
    @Column(name="mobilenumber")
    String mobileNumber;
    String address;
    String batch;
    String course;
    String gender;
    String year;

    Paramaterised constructor, getters-setters &  toString method 
}
```

StudentController.java

```
@GetMapping("/getpersonaldetails/{emailId}")
    public StudentDetail getPersonalDetails(@PathVariable String emailId)
    {
        emailId = emailId.substring(1);
        return studentService.getPersonalDetails(emailId);      
    }
```

StudentService.java

```
public StudentDetail getPersonalDetails(String emailId) {   
        return studentDao.getPersonalDetails(emailId);
}
```

StudentDAO.java

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM studentpersonaldetails WHERE emailId=?1", nativeQuery = true)
    StudentDetail getPersonalDetails(String emailId);
```

Error

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.cdac.hms.model.StudentDetail]
```

Comment: Can you please paste your entity also ? i.e. StudentDetail  ?

Comment: I have pasted the entity. Please see & give any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a new object of type StudentDetail and build it up with the results from. Then return that

```
var results = studentService.getPersonalDetails(emailId); 
StudentDetail sd = new StudentDetail(results);
return sd;
```

Answer (score 0):

the query is incorrect, you have to change the parameter.

try this code :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM studentpersonaldetails WHERE emailId= :emailId", nativeQuery = true)
    StudentDetail getPersonalDetails(String emailId);
```

Comment: Query is working perfectly. I am getting the result but in the String type.                         
error : nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.cdac.hms.model.StudentDetail]] with root cause

Answer (score 0):

You don't need native query to do this simple operation.  Following is the sample for findStudentByEmailId for repository interface.

```
@Query("SELECT student FROM studentpersonaldetails student WHERE student.emailId= :emailId")
StudentDetail findStudentByEmailId(@Param("emailId") String emailId);
```

Note: I have added param name and used it in Query.

Answer (score 0):

According to this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

You can have:
StudentDAO.java

```
public interface StudentDAO extends Repository<StudentDetail, String> {
  Optional<StudentDetail> findByEmailId(String emailId);
}
```

Also you could use plain StudentDetail instead of Optional